# NullReferenceException when instantiating prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors

Been running into a problem that seems to keep a temp variable from being assigned and instantiated. I believe it has to do with the If statement, when I remove the condition, it'll instantiate the prefab every frame so I believe the issue lies within the If statement itself

This is the full script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BPMinstantiator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject bpmOB;
    public GameObject bpmClone;

    public Conductor script;
    public Conductor offset;
    AudioSource song;

    float lastbeat; //this is the 'moving reference point'
    float bpm = 140;
    float dsptimesong;

    void Start()
    {

        Conductor script = bpmOB.GetComponent<Conductor>();
        song = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        Conductor offset = GetComponent<Conductor>();
        lastbeat = 0;
        script.crotchet = 60 / bpm;

        dsptimesong = (float)AudioSettings.dspTime;
        script.songposition = (float)(AudioSettings.dspTime - dsptimesong); //*song.pitch - offset;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log("update start");
        if (script.songposition > lastbeat + script.crotchet) //Issue here, removal fixes issue but causes clones to instantiate every frame
        {
            Debug.Log("If statement worked");
            bpmClone = Instantiate(bpmOB, new Vector2(0f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
            Debug.Log("clone is assigned");
            lastbeat += script.crotchet;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the specific region I'm looking into at the moment:

```
void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log("update start");
        if (script.songposition > lastbeat + script.crotchet) //Issue here, removal fixes issue but causes clones to instantiate every frame
        {
            Debug.Log("If statement worked");
            bpmClone = Instantiate(bpmOB, new Vector2(0f, 0f), Quaternion.identity);
            Debug.Log("clone is assigned");
            lastbeat += script.crotchet;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not a Unity guru, but my guess is that bpmOB.GetComponent<Conductor>() is not returning anything.

Comment: In other words, I think script is null.

Comment: hmm, I tried commenting that out yet I still got the null error. Something about this code doesn't want to assign bpmClone to anything afaik

Comment: you haven't assigned anything to the `script` member.

Comment: What is the value of script after bpmOB.GetComponent<Conductor>()

Comment: @David.Warwick hmmm, in all honesty I'm not entirely sure. I was following a unity tutorial for that part so the value of script is something I'm not entirely clear on. I *think* its used so I can call variables from a separate Class that I have.

Comment: Ok, someone else who is familiar with Unity will need to step in. Good luck.

Comment: Alrighty, appreciate your help!